# Can't raise the error in UserCreationForm in Django?

Tags: django

I want to raise the error in my UserCreationForm. I have seen previous questions on this problem but It's not working for me. I gave the existing email and when i submitted there's no error display on the page. Can you spot me the mistakes?

How I wrote in forms.py

```
class StudentRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', ....]
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email_attr = {'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'email-register', 'type': 'email'}

        super(StudentRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update(email_attr)
        # some other fields

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email's already taken!")
        return email
```

views.py

```
class StudentRegisterView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "attendance/login-register/student_register.html"
    form_class = StudentRegisterForm
    success_url = "/"
```

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint on the if statement and check if you get any CustomUser with that email?

Comment: I tried but i didn't get anything in that statement

Comment: So there is no such a User then. First, create a user with a particular email and then try to debug if you get anything by calling ```CustomUser.objcets.filter(email=email)```